# Explicit join Using multiple tables

Tags: explicit

I need to join 3 tables using an explicit join.  There is not a common key across all three tables.

Comment: do you have a common key for table1 and table2 and a different common key for table2 and table3?

Comment: What is the problem?  That you want to avoid getting duplicate rows because you'll be joining on non-key columns?

Comment: @Marco... Yes. the tables can be linked that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to join tables you need a common key for every pair.
So you can try something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id1 = t2.id1
INNER JOIN table3 t3
    ON t2.id2 = t3.id2
```

Comment: @Pepper: so, do you need something like my example? If not, provide more details please...

Comment: I believe this will work.  From my understanding this is postgresql and I am not familiar with it.  I've worked with all the other flavors just not this one.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, then I guess I've just never had to do one before *blush*